# jTextArea is not showing text properly

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a code that reads a line from a text file and displays it through a jtextArea with the variable name `txtFeedback`. I have used `txtFeedback.setText(tempInfo[3])` but it is not showing in the GUI,

i have used `System.out.println(tempInfo[3])` and it proves that theres a value inside. I will include snippets of the code below.

```java
                            file = new File("feedback.txt");
                            Scanner x = new Scanner(file);
                            String info;
                            while ((info = x.nextLine()) != null) {
                                String[] tempInfo = info.split("-");
                                if (tempInfo[1].equals(cbbOID.getSelectedItem().toString())) {

                                    //here
                                    System.out.println(tempInfo[3]);
                                    txtFeedback.setText(tempInfo[3]);
                                    //

                                    cbbRating.setSelectedItem(tempInfo[2]);
                                }
                            }
```

The output of the `System.out.println(tempInfo[3])` is `test`
Below is the image that shows that the jtextArea not showing the value.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `.append` instead?

Comment: Yes i did, ive searched for similar questions and most of them worked with append, but not mine :/

Comment: If it doesn't work then 1) you did not add the text area to the frame. That is maybe you created two instance of the text area and you are updating the text in the wrong text area or 2) maybe you update the text area in the loop, but then later in your code you clear the text in the text area. The problem is in your code. So post a proper [mre] that demonstrates the problem. That is create a JFrame with a JTextArea and a JButton. In the ActionListener of the button you simply `append(...)` text to the text area. This will prove that the append method works. Then debug your real application.